# Alternative for UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle Sql, I have to improve the code below by removing the use of union and obtaining the same result, however I am having trouble doing so.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ( (SELECT *
   FROM LINEITEM
   WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1992' AND
         L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT *
   FROM LINEITEM
   WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
         L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993')
   UNION
  (SELECT *
   FROM LINEITEM
   WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1993' AND
         L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1993'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT *
   FROM LINEITEM
   WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
         L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993') );
```

Comment: It is always helpful to explain what the code should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following query

```
select count(*) from (         
select distinct * from  LINEITEM
where L_SHIPDATE between DATE'1992-04-01' and DATE'1992-08-31' OR
      L_SHIPDATE between DATE'1993-01-01' and DATE'1993-04-30');
```

The `INTERSECT` you resolve with merging the two date predicates with `AND` which after a simplification gives the limited range.

Similar is valid for `UNION` where you use `OR`.

You will be ready if using `UNION ALL` and `INTERSECT ALL` (= new 21c [feature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF)).

As you are working with *set* operators, that remove duplicates you must add a `SELECT DISTINCT` (which would be again not necessary if your table contains PK).

Comment: `distinct *` almost never makes sense as `*` includes the PK columns and thus by definition there are no duplicates that the `distinct` could remove

Comment: Well @a_horse_with_no_name you are correct for `ANSI`  certified databases (i.e. all tables have PK defined). I use `distinct *` so that the query works on *all* tables...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can get rid of UNION but can definitely remove INTERSECT from your query. This query can be converted to -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM LINEITEM
         WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992'
           AND L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992'
         UNION
        SELECT *
          FROM LINEITEM
         WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1993'
           AND L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993'
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

With `SELECT *` you get complete rows of the table `LINEITEM`. And all your criteria is on the same column `L_SHIPDATE`. For `INTERSECT` this means that one row must match all conditions (`AND`):

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992'
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993'
```

is simply

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993'
```

or even simpler

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
      L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992'
```

as this covers both date ranges.

For `UNION` this means it must match either the first intersect conditions or the second ones (`OR`).

From

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM LINEITEM
  WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND
        L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992'
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM LINEITEM
  WHERE L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1993' AND
        L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993'
```

you get thus to

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE (L_SHIPDATE >= '01-APR-1992' AND L_SHIPDATE <= '31-AUG-1992')
   OR (L_SHIPDATE >= '01-JAN-1993' AND L_SHIPDATE <= '30-APR-1993')
```

As a footnote: Don't use string literals for dates. Use date literals:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM lineitem
WHERE (l_shipdate BETWEEN DATE '1992-04-01' AND DATE '1992-08-31')
   OR (l_shipdate BETWEEN DATE '1993-01-01' AND DATE '1993-04-30')
```

Comment: Oops, after writing all this, I see that Marmite Bomber has already said exactly the same. And they even pointed out that you must use `DISTINCT` in case two rows can contain exactly the same data and you want the same count as with `UNION`. I am not deleting my answer, but you should accept theirs.